# Correction to the Period of a Pendulum from the Buoyoancy of the Ball?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, buoyancy

In this [paper](http://fy.chalmers.se/~f7xiz/TIF080/pendulum.pdf) on calculating $g$ from the period of a pendulum they say that the correction from buoyancy is

\begin{equation}
 \frac{\Delta T}{T} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{m_a}{m}
 \end{equation}

But they give no justification and my calculations give something different. Does anyone know how they calculated this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the equation of motion, the force is not $mg$ but $(m-m_a)g$ so the period $T_0=2\pi(l/g)^{1/2}$ needs to be rewritten as $T=2\pi(l/g)^{1/2}(1-m_a/m)^{-1/2}=T_0(1-m_a/m)^{-1/2}$. The $\Delta T/T=(T-T_0)/T_0=(1-m_a/m)^{-1/2}-1$. In the limit of small $x$ one can use the approximation $(1-x)^p\approx 1-px$ so $\Delta T/T=1+1/2(m_a/m)-1$

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I got up to the last part but I didn't recognize that I could taylor expand it since the authors made it seem like an exact equation!